Ansible loop with when if some mounts are in place
I'm beginner with Ansible and I want to :

Check if mounts are in place
If mounts are not in place then mount files.

I'm trying to set this kind of Ansible, but without success :
---
- name: Check if filesystems are mounted
  shell: cat /proc/mounts | grep "{{ item.mountpoint }}"
  register: mounted_fs
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: False
  failed_when: False
  loop:
    - { mountpoint: '/fs1/data' }
    - { mountpoint: '/fs2/log' }
    - { mountpoint: '/fs3' }
    - { mountpoint: '/fs4' }
    
- name: Mount
  ansible.posix.mount:
      fstype: nfs
      opts: "{{ mount_options }}"
      src: "{{ lif_ip }}:{{ hana_data_junc_path }}"
      path: "{{ item.mountpoint }}"
      state: ephemeral
  become: yes
  when: mounted_fs.stdout == ""
  loop:
    - { mountpoint: '/fs1/data' }
    - { mountpoint: '/fs2/log' }
    - { mountpoint: '/fs3' }
    - { mountpoint: '/fs4' }

vars file I have in other location thats why I'm execute ansible with -e flag

The state ephemeral will "fail to avoid unexpected unmount or mount point override". Is this the case you want to handle?

For this moment I'm using this state. Now I'm thinking how I can implement case in my topic.
